# How do add an animated button in my css and html

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, button

I am new to CSS and downloaded a pre-made login page online.
I wanted to customize and add some effects when the user clicks the button and after 2 days of research but I got nothing.
It would be great if could get some tips on how do I set up.

this is the animation I am trying to achieve: "https://codemyui.com/submit-button-loading-animation-click/"

here's my HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.2/css/all.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="container" id="container">


        <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
                <form id="signup-form">
                    <h1>Create Account</h1>
                    <span><br>Use your Email for Registration</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="up_name" />
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="up_email"/>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="up_password"/>
                    <button id="signUpBtn">Sign Up</button>
                </form>
        </div>

        <div class="form-container sign-in-container">
                <form id="signin-form">
                    <h1>Sign in</h1>
                    <span><br>Use your Email Account to Login</span>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="in_email"/>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="in_password"/>
                    <button id="signInBtn">Sign In</button>
                </form>
        </div>

        <div class="overlay-container">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
                    <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
                    <p>To keep connected with us please login with your personal info</p>
                <button class="ghost" id="gotoSignIn">Sign In</button>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                    <h1>Hello, Friend!</h1>
                    <p>Enter your personal details and start journey with us</p>
                    <button class="ghost" id="gotoSignUp">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

    <script>
          var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyBCmpcDvnsftFfAIIodb5IgGUdpsiSAjwQ",
            authDomain: "feb-ekka.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://feb-ekka.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "feb-ekka",
            appId: "1:454540852080:web:0285ef92b9a933b28dedb5",
            measurementId: "G-Z8MLYNTN54"
          };

          firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
          firebase.analytics();

          const auth = firebase.auth();
          const db = firebase.firestore();

    </script>

    <script  src="script.js"></script>
    <script  src="authen.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

here's my CSS.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,800');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #f6f5f7;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin: 20px 0 30px;
}

span {
    font-size: 12px;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

button {
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #FF4B2B;
    background-color: #FF4B2B;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 45px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: transform 80ms ease-in;

}

button:active {
    transform: scale(0.95);
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

button.ghost {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
}

form {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 50px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

input {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 
            0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.form-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.sign-in-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-in-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.sign-up-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-up-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    animation: show 0.6s;
}

@keyframes show {
    0%, 49.99% {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    50%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 5;
    }
}

.overlay-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-container{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.overlay {
    background: #FF416C;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FF4B2B, #FF416C);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF4B2B, #FF416C);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay {
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.overlay-panel {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.overlay-right {
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-right {
    transform: translateX(20%);
}

.social-container {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.social-container a {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
}

footer p {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

footer i {
    color: red;
}

footer a {
    color: #3c97bf;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

my Script.js

```
const gotoSignUpButton = document.getElementById('gotoSignUp');
const gotoSignInButton = document.getElementById('gotoSignIn');
const container = document.getElementById('container');


gotoSignUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.add("right-panel-active");
});

gotoSignInButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.remove("right-panel-active");
});
```

and my authen.js (which I think isn't needed)

```
//listen for auth status changes

auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if(user != null){
          JavascriptInterface.toast("Login Successful!!");
          JavascriptInterface.openMain(user.uid);
    }

})

////logout
//const logout = document.querySelector('#lgout');
//logout.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
//    e.preventDefault();
//    auth.signOut();
//});

//signup
const signupForm = document.querySelector('#signup-form');
const signinForm = document.querySelector('#signin-form');

signupForm.addEventListener('submit',(e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    //get user Info
    const name = signupForm['up_name'].value;
    const email = signupForm['up_email'].value;
    const password = signupForm['up_password'].value;

    //signup the user
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then(cred => {
        return db.collection('users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({
            name: signupForm['up_name'].value,
            email: signupForm['up_email'].value,
            password: signupForm['up_password'].value
        })
    }).then(() => {
         signupForm.reset();
         container.classList.remove("right-panel-active");
    });
});


signinForm.addEventListener('submit',(e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    //get user Info
    const email = signinForm['in_email'].value;
    const password = signinForm['in_password'].value;

    //signin the user
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then(cred => {
                signinForm.reset();
        });
});


auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE)
```

Well Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not sure if my answer below would help.

Answer (score 0):

**Something like this?**

You can just change the styling and make it more appealing.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
      button.innerHTML = "Wait...";
      button.classList.add("loading");
      button.classList.remove("submit");
    
    
    setTimeout(function()
    {
      if(button.classList.contains("loading"))
      {
        button.classList.remove("loading");
        button.innerHTML = "Success";
        button.classList.add("success");
      }
    }, 3000);
});
```

```css
@keyframes rotate{
  from{
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  to{
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
.container{
  width: 180px;
}
div#button{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.loading{
  max-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: transparent #27a80c transparent #27a80c;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #27a80c;
  
  animation: rotate 1s infinite;
}

.submit, .success{
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 120px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: thin solid transparent;
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color color .25s ease;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
}

.submit{
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
}
.success{
  border-color: #27a80c;
  color: white;
  background-color: #27a80c;
}

.submit:hover{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="submit" id="button">
    Submit
  </div>
</div>
```